# Why doesn't return getter like in Java (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, output, getter, setter

I want to move from Java to C# and I want to try getter and setter like in Java

```
internal class Person
    {
 
        internal string name;
        

        internal void setName (string name)
        {
            this.name = name;   
        }

        internal string getName ()
        {
            return this.name;
        }

    }
```

in main:

```
Person alex = new Person();
alex.setName("alex");
Console.WriteLine(alex.getName);
```

and the output is:

```
System.Func`1[System.String]
```

Why doesn't display the expected "alex" ?

Comment: You're missing the paranethesis "()". 

`Console.WriteLine(alex.getName())`

Comment: Apart from the console issue, use [C# properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) instead. A `Person` has a `Name` and not a `SetName`/`GetName`.

Comment: Should be `Console.WriteLine(alex.getName())` or better real C# properties.

Comment: Marking everything `internal` is probably also not what you want -- if the field has the same accessibility as its getter/setter, nothing prevents clients from manipulating it directly. In C# code you'd expect `public string Name { get; set; }`.

Comment: Use properties. C# isn't Java and properties are actual concepts, parts of an object's API. They aren't just getter and setter methods. Serializers and ORMs will serialize and map properties, not fields. No library will use methods that just have the `get` and `set` prefix

Comment: This is actually a frequent mistake people make in moving between languages - they assume the idioms and patterns they've picked up in a previous language are universally applicable and then try to use those in the new language. It doesn't help you learn the language if you're writing unidiomatic code that no "native" author of the new language would use.

Comment: I don't know much about Java but I'm pretty sure that calling the getter method require brackets: `alex.getName()` - and this will also work for C#. But please use real properties because C# is not Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because getName is a function, and not a getter. So your code should be

```
Console.WriteLine(alex.getName());
```

If you want to use setter and getters, the syntax is

```
internal class Person
{
  internal string name;
  internal string Name 
  {
    set { this.name = value; }
    get { return this.name; }
  }
}
```

Or more compact

```
internal class Person
{
  internal string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The `name` field shouldn't be `internal`. Fields are just implementation details. Only properties are part of a class's programming surface

Comment: I can see cases, not really recommended, when you want to set the field directly without passing through the setter. That's why I maintained the original Access modifiers from the question. But it is a valid note.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, properties are used instead of explicit setters/getters. So the above is better written as

```cs
internal string Name
{
    get => this.name
    set => this.name = value;
}
```

or even shorter, with automatic properties:

```cs
internal string Name
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Additionally, in your statement `Console.WriteLine(alex.getName);` `getName` is the method, not it's result, therefore it prints the type of the method. To fix that, change it to `Console.WriteLine(alex.getName());` or, with the above property, it will be `Console.WriteLine(alex.Name));`

Comment: It's not just better, properties are part of an object's API. Fields and `get`-prefixed methods aren't. Serializers, ORMs, Web frameworks etc all work on properties, none on fields or methods unless *explicitly*  configured

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sure, but nevertheless (if you don't need any of that), it's just syntax. It doesn't really change the behavior when looking at the class alone.

Comment: It's not just syntax, yes, it changes behavior. Properties are specified in an assembly's metadata. You can use `Type.GetProperty` to get a property by name. You can specify properties in interfaces, but not fields. If you use any king of configuration or settings infrastructure, properties are used. You'd have to strip quite a lot of basic functionality to say `it's just syntax`.

Comment: I see it the other way round: _Because_ we have properties, they're used in many places where it's convenient, like Serializers. But there's nothing that would prevent a library to use `Type.GetField` instead of `Type.GetProperty`. And (as in the example above), `setXYZ` and `getXYZ` methods can be part of an interface.

Comment: That's an opinion that contradicts the language design (actually, the runtime design) itself

Comment: Are you sure? Sounds more like a hen-and-egg problem to me.